# Google Apps Script how to use page name to query google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a simple Google Site setup that runs a Web App that queries a Google Sheet, and returns templated html code with the necessary queried information. I would like to add functionality that allows the Script to query the Sheet using the Page Name from where the Web App is embedded.

So, for example, say my website is: https://sites.google.com/view/SOMESITE

Say it has a few pages such as:

- https://sites.google.com/view/SOMESITE/Dave
- https://sites.google.com/view/SOMESITE/Rick

What I want to do is embed my web app in each of these sheets, and use the respective page name (i.e. Dave or Rick) as a parameter to refine the query the Web App does.

I have tried this, but the 'page' comes back Null.

```
var page = SitesApp.getActivePage();
var name = Logger.log(page.getName());
```

How can I get the page name as a variable to use in my Script/Web App?

***UPDATE:***

I have revised my approach per the comments. So let's say I have the URL to my WebApp like this:

https://www.somedomain.com/blah/blah?Rick

And this is my Web App Code:

**DoGet:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var name = e.queryString
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

**getData**

```
function getData() {

     // ...here there is a bunch of code extracting data from my spreadsheet

      return [pick, title, artist, name]

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>

    <? var data = getAlbum(); ?>
  // ... the rest is a bunch of markup that makes a table of the query results from getData
```

How to I pass the variable 'name', which should equal "Rick", to my getData function so I can use it when querying my Sheet?

Comment: How about adding it to the query string in the Url.

Comment: Can't lie, I'm not exactly sure what that means or how to accomplish it.

Comment: `https://www.domaint.com/blah/blah?key=value....`

Comment: Very often when I build mulltipage webapps that's one way that I used to go to different pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass query parameters to your Web App URL, you can check [here](https://branch.io/glossary/query-parameters/) what query parameters are and how to use them. For example:

```
 https://www.somedomain.com/blah/blah?name=Rick
```

With the `parameter` attribute from the `e` [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters), you can get the object with all the parameters you passed to the get request. You can use these values directly in your code.gs file, for example:

**DoGet:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var parameters = e.parameter;
  getData(parameters);
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

**getData**

```
function getData(parameters) {
 // ...here there is a bunch of code extracting data from my spreadsheet
  return [pick, title, artist, name]
}
```

Finally, if you need to communicate between the HTML file and the code.gs file, you should check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) for it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have enough room for this in the comments.  But this is what the `doGet()` might look like:

```
function doGet(e) 
{
  //Logger.log('query params: ' + Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
  if(e.queryString !=='')
  {  
    switch(e.parameter.mode)
    {
      case 'page4':
        setPage('Page4')      
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page4')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page4"); 
        break;  
      case 'page3':
        setPage('Page3');        
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page3')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page3");
        break;
      case 'page2':
        setPage('Page2');        
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page2')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page2");
        break;  
      case 'page1':
         setPage('Page1');
         return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page1");
        break;
      default:
        setPage('Page1');
        return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
        .evaluate()
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        .setTitle("Page1");
        break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    setPage('Page1');
    return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('Page1')
    .evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("Page1");
  }
}
```

[Requirements for WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)

Comment: Okay, so that has presented a second issue. How do I pass the "e" from my DoGet to a "GetData" function? I'll add my code to my initial post.

Comment: Please read Requirements for Webapps.  The link has just been placed into my answer.